# Step motors vibrate, don't move at all (Prusa I3)

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

Recently, I changed my RAMPS 1.4 card (because there was a problem with the power output).So I bought this new one, and  an Arduino Mega.I didn'T change the code (Marlin 1.3.3).I used the same stepsticks (a4988).I plugged my motors to the Ramps card. When I give them the command to turn they started to turn but didn't stop.Stepsticks got hot.After some time I tried it again and they just vibrated.The stepsticks got insanely hot after just 5-6 seconds.I used a different stepstick RAMPS card and Mega, they worked perfectly.But when I plugged the stepstick to the new card, the motors did te same thing again.
What can be causing this and how can I fix it?
(I've measured the voltage input, it is 12V and stable)

Comment: Sounds like something about your card is faulty.  However, *repair* and *usage* questions are not on topic here unless accompanied by actual engineering references.  You should seek support from the vendor or the 3d printing community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to tune the current that the stepper drivers are delivering.

First, you have to find what setting gets your stepper moving. The way I usually do this is by first turning the potentiometer on the stepper driver all the way counterclockwise. This will turn the current all the way down. Then, turn the pot clockwise by about 1/4 of a turn. See if the motor moves. Keep doing this until the motor moves. Then, turn the pot down a little bit, maybe by 1/8 of a turn. The idea is that you want to figure out what setting is required for your motor to turn, then turn your driver up just a tiny bit past that.

Once you find the right current limit both your motor and driver should operate fine. They may get a little warm but they shouldn't get hot.

Comment: This is unlikely to explain both the failure to turn *and* the **"stepsticks got insanely hot after just 5-6 seconds"** - which probably indicates a serious electrical fault, not just a current adjustment issue.

Comment: I disagree. I've observed the same behavior when my current settings were not tuned properly. This isn't to say its not an electrical fault, just putting in my two cents.